# Arithmetic operands type casting

Tags: c++

Why in the following code:

```
short a = 4;
char b = 2;
cout << sizeof(a/b);
```

sizeof(a/b) is 4? Why is not 2 as size of short?

Comment: Because the `a/b` is an integer value and the `sizeof(int)` is 4

Comment: `auto c = a/b; cout << sizeof(c);` will be 4.

Comment: Ron's reply isn't incorrect ... but Mandy007's comment is better.  Your example illustrates [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).  Eljay's comment is just a [tautology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology)

Comment: @FoggyDay Now corrected :)

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, bu there are no type casts in this code. The behavior here involves a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: What you have posted is different than `sizeof(a) / sizeof(b)`.

Comment: @Ron - corrections noted.  Great response :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is `4` because the type of the expression `a / b` is `int` and not `short`.
Excerpt from the *The C++ Programming Language* book:

> Before an arithmetic operation is performed, [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) is
>   used to create ints out of shorter integer types.

So, now your (shorter integers) `a` and `b` operands are promoted to be of type `int`. Thus the whole `a / b` expression becomes `int` and the size of type `int` is likely to be `4` bytes on your machine.

The [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator in your case returns the size of the type of the expression which is `int`, which is `4`. The `sizeof` operator can return:

- the size of the type
- the size of the type of an expression

This type conversion is not called *type casting* but *integral promotion*.